# Neural Network Test doesn't work CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've just started learning python and Deep Learning with the book Deep Learning with Python by François Chollet, but the test example (pg.27) gets stuck in the first epoch.

It is on Windows, in a created Anaconda enviroment where it is only installed jupyter, spyder, tensorflow gpu and keras gpu with Python version 3.5.6 because the versions above 3.6 weren't working.

What is wrong?

```
    from keras.datasets import mnist
    (train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

    from keras import models
    from keras import layers
    network = models.Sequential()
    network.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(28 * 28,)))
    network.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

    network.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    train_images = train_images.reshape((60000, 28 * 28))
    train_images = train_images.astype('float32') / 255
    test_images = test_images.reshape((10000, 28 * 28))
    test_images = test_images.astype('float32') / 255

    from keras.utils import to_categorical
    train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels)
    test_labels = to_categorical(test_labels)

    network.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5, batch_size=128)
```

It gets stuck in this:

```
Epoch 1/5
```

The error

---

```
InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-63880145b61b> in <module>()
     19 test_labels = to_categorical(test_labels)
     20 
---> 21 network.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5, batch_size=128)

C:\Users\\.conda\envs\tf-gpu-ide\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
   1035                                         initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
   1036                                         steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
-> 1037                                         validation_steps=validation_steps)
   1038 
   1039     def evaluate(self, x=None, y=None,

C:\Users\\.conda\envs\tf-gpu-ide\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_arrays.py in fit_loop(model, f, ins, out_labels, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_f, val_ins, shuffle, callback_metrics, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps)
    197                     ins_batch[i] = ins_batch[i].toarray()
    198 
--> 199                 outs = f(ins_batch)
    200                 outs = to_list(outs)
    201                 for l, o in zip(out_labels, outs):

C:\Users\\.conda\envs\tf-gpu-ide\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   2664                 return self._legacy_call(inputs)
   2665 
-> 2666             return self._call(inputs)
   2667         else:
   2668             if py_any(is_tensor(x) for x in inputs):

C:\Users\\.conda\envs\tf-gpu-ide\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in _call(self, inputs)
   2634                                 symbol_vals,
   2635                                 session)
-> 2636         fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
   2637         return fetched[:len(self.outputs)]
   2638 

C:\Users\\.conda\envs\tf-gpu-ide\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1380           ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(
   1381               self._session._session, self._handle, args, status,
-> 1382               run_metadata_ptr)
   1383         if run_metadata:
   1384           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

C:\Users\\.conda\envs\tf-gpu-ide\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py in __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
    517             None, None,
    518             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
--> 519             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
    520     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive
    521     # as there is a reference to status from this from the traceback due to

InternalError: Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(128, 512), b.shape=(512, 10), m=128, n=10, k=512
     [[Node: dense_2/MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@training/RMSprop/gradients/dense_2/MatMul_grad/MatMul_1"], transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](dense_1/Relu, dense_2/kernel/read)]]
     [[Node: metrics/acc/Mean/_53 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_362_metrics/acc/Mean", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

The jupyter notebook LOG:

```
2022-05-16 09:00:15.130789: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
2022-05-16 09:00:15.256866: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1405] Found device 0 with properties:
name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti major: 8 minor: 6 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.665
pciBusID: 0000:07:00.0
totalMemory: 8.00GiB freeMemory: 6.99GiB
2022-05-16 09:00:15.256962: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1484] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2022-05-16 09:00:15.802752: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:965] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2022-05-16 09:00:15.802829: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971]      0
2022-05-16 09:00:15.803036: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] 0:   N
2022-05-16 09:00:15.803133: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1097] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6724 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:07:00.0, compute capability: 8.6)
2022-05-16 09:00:16.362403: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:647] failed to run cuBLAS routine cublasSgemm_v2: CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED
```

In case it is relevant, other info about the configuration:

```
nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_May__3_19:00:59_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.7, V11.7.64
Build cuda_11.7.r11.7/compiler.31294372_0


conda list keras
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
keras-applications        1.0.4                    py35_1
keras-base                2.2.2                    py35_0
keras-gpu                 2.2.2                         0
keras-preprocessing       1.0.2                    py35_1
```

General Enviroment

```
numba -s

__Time Stamp__
Report started (local time)                   : 2022-05-16 09:11:51.541010
UTC start time                                : 2022-05-16 12:11:51.541010
Running time (s)                              : 4.864708

__Hardware Information__
Machine                                       : AMD64
CPU Name                                      : generic
CPU Count                                     : 12
Number of accessible CPUs                     : 12
List of accessible CPUs cores                 : 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
CFS Restrictions (CPUs worth of runtime)      : None

Memory Total (MB)                             : 16295
Memory Available (MB)                         : 7940

__OS Information__
Platform Name                                 : Windows-10-10.0.19043-SP0
Platform Release                              : 10
OS Name                                       : Windows
OS Version                                    : 10.0.19043
OS Specific Version                           : 10 10.0.19043 SP0 Multiprocessor Free
Libc Version                                  : ?

__Python Information__
Python Compiler                               : MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)
Python Implementation                         : CPython
Python Version                                : 3.9.7

__Numba Toolchain Versions__
Numba Version                                 : 0.55.1
llvmlite Version                              : 0.38.0

__LLVM Information__
LLVM Version                                  : 11.1.0

__CUDA Information__
CUDA Device Initialized                       : True
CUDA Driver Version                           : (11, 7)
CUDA Runtime Version                          : 11070
CUDA NVIDIA Bindings Available                : False
CUDA NVIDIA Bindings In Use                   : False
CUDA Detect Output:
Found 1 CUDA devices
id 0    b'NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti'                              [SUPPORTED]
                      Compute Capability: 8.6
                           PCI Device ID: 0
                              PCI Bus ID: 7
                                    UUID: GPU-ac925103-25ce-7d00-18b3-0a068631b05d
                                Watchdog: Enabled
                            Compute Mode: WDDM
             FP32/FP64 Performance Ratio: 32
Summary:
        1/1 devices are supported

CUDA Libraries Test Output:
Finding nvvm from CUDA_HOME
        named  nvvm64_40_0.dll
        trying to open library...       ok
Finding cudart from CUDA_HOME
        named  cudart64_110.dll
        trying to open library...       ok
Finding cudadevrt from CUDA_HOME
        named  cudadevrt.lib
        ERROR: failed to find cudadevrt:
cudadevrt.lib not found
Finding libdevice from CUDA_HOME
        searching for compute_20...     ok
        searching for compute_30...     ok
        searching for compute_35...     ok
        searching for compute_50...     ok


__SVML Information__
SVML State, config.USING_SVML                 : True
SVML Library Loaded                           : True
llvmlite Using SVML Patched LLVM              : True
SVML Operational                              : True

__Threading Layer Information__
TBB Threading Layer Available                 : True
+-->TBB imported successfully.
OpenMP Threading Layer Available              : True
+-->Vendor: MS
Workqueue Threading Layer Available           : True
+-->Workqueue imported successfully.

__Numba Environment Variable Information__
None found.

__Conda Information__
Conda Build                                   : 3.21.8
Conda Env                                     : 4.12.0
Conda Platform                                : win-64
Conda Python Version                          : 3.9.7.final.0
Conda Root Writable                           : False
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to the version incompatibility. As per the official documentation, Tensorflow supports up to `CUDA 11.2` but you are using `CUDA 11.7`. Please uninstall `CUDA 11.7` and install `CUDA 10.1` from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.1-download-archive-base) as it is compatible with Tensorflow 2.2. To set up the GPU, follow the instructions from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows_1). For more details, please refer to the [tested build configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu). Thank you!